# How do the x and y parameters in the Label object work for bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

[I've read the documentation for the Label class in Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#labels) but the `x` and `y` parameters are quite confusing. Their behavior seems to change if you pass something to the `x_units` and `y_units` parameters but I don't understand what the units are supposed to be by default.

More specifically, I have a list of strings that I'm using for my x-axis:

```
    xlab = [
            'COREPCE2', 
            'COREPCE3', 
            'COREPCE4', 
            'COREPCE5', 
            'COREPCE6', 
            '',
            'T5YIE'
    ]
    p = figure(..., y_range = (0,.04), x_range = xlab)
```

If I wanted to draw basically anything else on the plot, I could just use those strings. For example I drew some lines like this:

```
    p.line(['COREPCE2', 'T5YIE'], [.02,.02], color = 'black', line_dash = 'dashed')
    p.line(['', ''], [0,.04], color = 'black')
```

And that works fine, [this is the full chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfSI1.png).

Here's the issue though. I want to put a text label on the "COREPCE4" location of the x axis. If I try just passing the string for the `x` parameter in the Label class it just doesn't work:

```
    section = Label(x = 'COREPCE4', y = .03, text = 'Survey of Professional Forecasters: August 9, 2019')
    p.add_layout(section)
```

It throws an error: `ValueError: expected a value of type Real, got COREPCE4 of type str`. I don't really know what units its expecting. Is there a way to make Bokeh recognize that I want to use the x-axis label as my `x` parameter in the same way I've done with the other glyphs?

Answer (score 1):

The propertied `x_units`, `y_units`, refer to screen (pixel) vs data-space (axis) units. As of Bokeh 1.3.4 the `x` and `y` properties of `Label` can only be set from floating point numbers, so they cannot be used directly with categorical coordinates. For now you should use `LabelSet`, even if you are only showing a single label, since it can work with categorical coordinates.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering! So I tried using LabelSet like this:
`labels = LabelSet(x = ['2019','Nowcast', '5 Years'], y = [ymax - .002]*3, text = [
            'Summary of Economic Projections - PCE Inflation: March 20, 2019',
            'Survey of Professional Forecasters: 2019Q3, August 9, 2019',
            'TIPS Spread: last six weeks'
            ])`
but it doesn't seem to work. it throws the same value error.

Comment: I also changed the chart a bit more since i posted this: https://i.imgur.com/jtDwBKr.png

Comment: I can't really speculate more without actual code to run and evaluate.